# How to change a specific value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I try to replace Latitude value for Chelsea, but have not been successful. There is no errors reported after I execute:

```
sales_data['Latitude'] = sales_data['Latitude'].replace(51.487542, 40.740657)
```

However, the data remains the same.

Can someone please help on this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZTtv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Strange it should work.  The only explanation I see is that the Latidude column is not a *float64* column.
Try the following:

```
sales_data['Latitude'] = sales_data['Latitude'].replace('51.487542', '40.740657')
```

If this does not work please post the result of *print(sales_data.dtypes)* and maybe some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason may be truncation: probably what you see as `51.487542` is the truncation of a value with more digits.

You can verify this possibility printing the value of the cell containing it.

Otherwise you may first run `sales_data = sales_data.round(6)` to round every element of the table to the 6th decimal number, and then try to replace.

Comment: thanks alot. 
running sales_data = sales_data.round(6) helped.